# htaccess specific folder redirecting to sub domain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been having trouble using .htaccess to redirect any path starting with a specific directory to a sub domain. The main issue may be the directory actually exists as it is what my sub domain points to. I am not concerned about maintaining the path, redirecting to the home page for each is fine. I also need this for several specific domains ie:

```
website.com/foo -> foo.website.com
website.com/foo/about.html -> foo.website.com
website.com/foo/other/index.html -> foo.website.com

website.com/bar -> foo.website.com
website.com/foo/about.html -> foo.website.com
website.com/foo/other/index.html -> foo.website.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to `Redirect` a specific folder to a specific host. As an alternative to using `mod_rewrite` you could use [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) and `RedirectMatch`.

```
RedirectMatch ^/foo[$/]? http://foo.website.com/
RedirectMatch ^/bar[$/]? http://foo.website.com/
```

You could of course add more rules to fit your setup.

Answer (score 0):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^foo\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(foo|bar)(/.*)?$ http://foo.%{HTTP_HOST}/ [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Will this work for the `website.com/bar -> foo.website.com` case?

Comment: Made some edit. You had some duplicates in your example and I thought you wanted to redirect `website.com/bar -> bar.website.com` that is why I made my solution generic.